# Optimization in selection and scaling to fit a target

Tags: python, optimization, data-fitting

I have a suite of 1000 signals and a target power spectral density. I don't want to intervene in the signals, but only scaling them (from 0.5 to 3.0 - ideally closer to 1.0).

I want to select the N best (say 10) out of 1000, that when scaled from 0.5 to 3.0 (up to the second decimal - e.g. 0.78), match on average the best way my target.

However, there are constraints on the average of the 10 signals (cannot exceed or be less than the target by a specific percentage).

Any ideas on how to use a genetic algorithm to find an optimal solution? Brute forcing it would kill my pc :P

Comment: In addition, I'm trying to find a technique to enforce a smaller standard deviation within a frequency range of interest.

Comment: No ideas? I'm trying to use the pandas data frame instead of classes to organize my data.